# Text Editor - Zoom Out to Multiple Pages

Tags: vim, ms-word, notepad++, sublimetext, text-editor

MS Word has a feature called **Zoom to Multiple Views**. As you zoom out a page, when it is able to fit two pages, it will do that automatically. Here is the settings. (More info about [Multiple Pages in Word](http://www.howtogeek.com/215187/how-to-view-multiple-pages-at-once-in-word/))

[image: Multiple Pages Settings]

Is such functionality possible in Text Editor (Notepad++, Sublime Text, Vim etc)? It may be useful, to zoom out the source code, to fit much more visible code to second view? Most of the time, some of the **precious screen real-estate is wasted in white space** on right side. This is especially true for many wide-screen monitors.

- I am aware that I can clone my source code to have two views. But I am looking for much implicit behavior.
- I am also aware that I can rotate my monitor for good portrait view. But this is not feasible.

Here is what I am proposing.

[image]

Any ideas, solutions or comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [MPage plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545): Shows synchronized pages of a file in multiple windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in vim.

**Idea:**

You can open the same buffer in another window using the command `:vsplit %`
and then create a function that will control the automatic scroll of the new window according to the original one.

Comment: Poor man's Follow Mode (emacs) by Chip Campbell
`command! -bar FollowMode vsplit|wincmd l|exe "norm! Ljz\<cr>"|set scb|wincmd p|set scb`

Comment: Really awesome ! :)

Comment: I saw [this follow mode demo in emacs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPFvM63CTTM). That is precisely what I am looking for in `VIM`.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from multiple sources. I have added the link at the bottom.

Here is the command that I used in my `vimrc` file. I am using **GVim**.

```
" split screen and automatic scroll
" emacs follow: scroll bind two windows one screen apart
  nmap <silent> <Leader>ef  :vsplit<bar>wincmd l<bar>exe "norm! Ljz<c-v><cr>"   <cr>:set scb<cr>:wincmd h<cr>:set scb<cr>
```

I did face one issue though. I am using `mswin.vim` for some windows related functionality. Which includes `<Ctrl+V`for pasting. The above command conflicted with it. So, I had to modify the `mswin.vim` to comment out `Ctrl + V` related settings. Here is what I did.

```
" CTRL-V and SHIFT-Insert are Paste
" ac 2017/01/26 Removed ctrl + v paste capability, as it conflicts with others
" map <C-V>     "+gP
" map <S-Insert>        "+gP
" cmap <C-V>        <C-R>+
" cmap <S-Insert>       <C-R>+
```

After this trick, I was able to get the vertical split with nice interactive scroll. I loved this feature. Thank you all for help.

([Got a help from this page, thanks.](http://vim_use.narkive.com/b4VuuClt/emacs-follow-mode-in-vim))

Comment: there were some issues of the above method with the vim folds. I think Ingo Karkat's solution below is a better option.